# Как определить новости на одну тему с разных сайтов?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Пишу парсер, собирающий свежие новости с крупных новостных порталов. Часто возникает ситуация, когда несколько сайтов выкладывают новость на одну и ту же тему под разными заголовками, например:

- interfax.ru: Капков ушел в отставку с
  поста главы департамента культуры
  Москвы
- top.rbc.ru: На место Сергея
  Капкова назначен глава Мосгорнаследия
- vesti.ru: Сергей Капков покинул
  правительство Москвы
- lenta.ru: Собянин принял отставку
  Капкова
  )

От таких дублей надо избавиться, а как - я не могу придумать.
Сами заголовки были мной изрядно помучены, но в примере, например, в первых двух заголовках только два одинаковых слова. По текстам вычислять сходство я даже не брался, т.к. не знаю,с какой стороны подступится. Да и подозреваю я,что их тексты антиплагиат в схожести не уличит, куда уж мне.
Что посоветуете?

P.S. Парсер работает на стандартном наборе: php+curl, mysql, ajax итд.
Статьи берутся [отсюда](http://mediametrics.ru/rating/ru/online.js?search=&per_page=125;geo=auto), парсятся регулярками по мере появления новых в топе и заносятся в бд, есть white-list доменов.

Comment: Без серьезного агрегата анализа это невозможно, как и писать/поддерживать его в одиночку.

Comment: Посоветую заняться машинным обучением и может лет через цать у Вас что-то получится.

Comment: Парсить надо сразу рамблер или яндекс. Там уже все сгруппировано :)

Comment: Ваша проблема [AI-complete](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/A/AI-complete.html).

Answer (score 1):

Можно долго придумывать как и что сделать, но без человеческого вмешательства это работать не будет, так как текст пишут для людей, в конце концов.

Простейший способ для облегчения работы модератора: Группировать новости по времени и совпадающим значимым словам (возможно: белый список слов). Из приведённого примера - если новости появились в течении N времени, то ввиду того что в них всех встречается "Капков" то возможно это новости об одном и том же, так что предложить модератору рассмотреть эти новости пачкой, а человек уже пусть решает.

Answer (score 1):

Задача довольно сложная на самом деле. Вам нужно понять, о чем же говорится в новости, составить на некотором языке описание новости, в которое будут включены ключевые факты по новости. Затем, новости кластеризуются в пространстве ключевых факторов.

Задачу решает, например, Яндекс.Новости, которая группирует их автоматически. Они используют свой [Томита парсер](https://github.com/yandex/tomita-parser) для выделения фактов (а это самая сложная часть задачи), на сколько я знаю. Если он вам подходит по лицензии, то можете начать плясать от него.